# Perl CGI and Javascript: Dynamic Dependant Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, perl, cgi

I am normally a C/C++ programmer, but my job thinks all software is the same so I have to make a webpage to input information into a mysql database. Since one of the other programmers uses Perl CGI for all of our internal webpages I have decided to use that for consistency's sake.

I have a few different hashes to store the information that I need from the database to create the dropdowns. here are what the hashes contain:

`%issues` (IssueID : Issue)(issue id with name of issues)

`%step`   (StepID  : Step)(stepid with name of step)

`%stepissueid` (StepID : IssueID) (linking different steps to take to a particular issue)

Perl/HTML creating dropdown for issue *dropdown for issue works* *second dependant drop down doesn't*

```
#begin Issue Drop Down 
print "<td valign=\"top\" colspan=1><font $c2> Issue:<br> ";
$temp = scalar keys %issue;
print "<select id='Issue1' name=\"optone\"";
print "onchange=\"setOptions(document.myform.optone.options[document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value);\">";
foreach my $x (sort(keys %issue))
{
    if ($x == $issueid)
    {
        print "<OPTION selected=selected value=\"$x\"> $issue{$x}</OPTION>"; 
    }
    else
    {
         print "<OPTION value=\"$x\"> $issue{$x}</OPTION>"; 
    }
}
print "</select>";

print "<select name=\"opttwo\" size=\"1\">";
print "<option>Please select one of the options above first</option>";
print "</select>";
```

The Javascript for setOptions: since I don't know how many elements or what they are I created  a loop to create the javascript and multiple if statements

```
print "<head>";
print "<script language=\"JavaScript\">";
print "<!--";
print "function setOptions(chosen){";
print "var selbox=document.myform.opttwo;";
print "selbox.options.length = 0;";

foreach my $x (sort(keys %issue))
{
    print "if (chosen == $x)";
    {
        foreach my $y (sort(keys %step))
        {
            if ($stepissueid{$y} == $x)
            {
                print "selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new";
                print "Options('$step{$y}','$y');";
            }
        }
    }
}
print "}";
print "//-->";
print "</script>";
 print "</head>";
```

EDIT: I am pretty sure there was an invisible control character that was making things mess up because I literally re-typed it and everything worked. Now the problem that I am having is that I receive information from the DB and I want to have the step dropdown be auto selected as well if an option has already been chosen (I know a good amount of inactivity time, I had other more important projects to work on)

I tried adding a  `onselect=\"setOptions(document.myform1.optone.options[document.myform1.optone.selectedIndex].value);\">`
 under the opttwo select HTML but that did nothing (trying to call my JS funcition during the second dropdown to autofill)

Comment: what is actual and what is desired output?

Comment: Acctual: Drop down 1 contains 3 issues and dropdown 2 contains only "Please select one of the options above first"

Comment: Desired: Dropdown 1 contain 3 issues and dropdown 2 contains steps to solve particular issue that is selected in Dropdown 1 (found from %step)

Comment: since you are already using javascript, may I suggest perl only generating `JSON` and javascript do the rest?

Comment: I got most of my javascript code from here [link](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldydrop1.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a Javascript error in your second block of code?

```
print "<!--";
```

should be

```
print "//<!--";
```

This could make the js function non-functional, resulting in what you are seeing.

**Perl Recommendation**

I suggest you make your javascript and HTML more readable using a Perl print structure like this:

```
#begin Issue Drop Down 
$temp = scalar keys %issue;
print<<HTML_JS_EOF;
<td valign="top" colspan=1><font $c2> Issue:<br>
<select id='Issue1' name="optone"
onchange="setOptions(document.myform.optone.options[document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
HTML_JS_EOF
foreach my $x (sort(keys %issue))
{
    if ($x == $issueid)
    {
        print "<OPTION selected=selected value=\"$x\"> $issue{$x}</OPTION>"; 
    }
    else
    {
         print "<OPTION value=\"$x\"> $issue{$x}</OPTION>"; 
    }
}
print<<HTML_JS_EOF;
</select>

<select name="opttwo" size="1">
<option>Please select one of the options above first</option>
</select>
HTML_JS_EOF
```

Comment: I made the change in my js to "//<!--" but there wasn't any display difference. Is there a possibility that "chosen" isn't being sent to the js correctly, because I printed what the js looks like after being created and it is

Comment: function setOptions(chosen){
var selbox=document.myform.opttwo;
selbox.option.length = 0;
if (chosen == "1"){
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('Clean Nozzle','1');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('Fix Bobbles','2');
}

Comment: You should make sure your hashes have data in them. Your perl code won't populate the HTML options if the %issue and %step hashes don't have a matching key that is chosen. Try the Dump::Dumper module. Then 'print "<pre>",Dumper [\%issue,\%step],"</pre>;'

Comment: The point of `<!--` at the start of a script element is to prevent the element from rendering in browsers that don't support HTML past version 2. Putting `//` in front of it would defeat the object. (Since nobody uses browsers that old now, including it is pointless anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a real need to reinvent the wheel the hardest way possible? Use [Ext JS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) for the client side and [RPC::ExtDirect](https://metacpan.org/pod/RPC%3a%3aExtDirect) for the server side instead, will save you tons of time.